# c# | the type or namespace ParamaterizedThreadStart does not exist

Tags: c#

Okay so essentially this is happening:

I am trying to run a

```
Thread tcpHandlerThread = new ParamaterizedThreadStart(tcpHandler);
```

but I get the error

> the type or namespace ParamaterizedThreadStart does not exist

on ParamaterizedThreadStart but I have these imports:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question :\ What imports am I missing or is it just an error with my Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ParameterizedThreadStart` is a `delegate`.

use this instead..

```
Thread tcpHandlerThread = new Thread(tcpHandler);
```

If you want to run methods with parameters. you can use this..

```
Thread tcpHandlerThread = new Thread(() => tcpHandler(parameters));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you misspelled the  `ParameterizedThreadStart` class.

The link below might help you and has a good example how to create a parameterized thread.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h2f2459%28v=vs.110%29.aspx